# Select with WITH

Tags: sql-server

I am new in MySQL I have a db2 select and a would like to do this in MSsql and with WITH clause

db2

1 SQL.

```
    SELECT
           SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ.SIFRA3,
           SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ.SIFVAL32,
           SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ.DATUM,
           SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ.RAZMERJE
        FROM
           SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ
        WHERE
           (
              (SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ.DATUM >= '1.5.2007')
           ) ---> this go to DW.TEMP_PFPC_TT_VALUTRAZ
```

2 sql.

```
 SELECT
            '705' AS SIFRA3,
            '891' AS SIFVAL32,
            A.DATUM,
            A.RAZMERJE AS RAZMERJE
        FROM
            DW.TEMP_PFPC_TT_VALUTRAZ A
        WHERE
            A.DATUM >= '1.5.2007' AND
            A.SIFRA3 = '891' AND
            A.SIFVAL32 = '978' AND
            ('705', '891', A.DATUM) NOT IN
                (
                SELECT
                    SIFRA3,
                    SIFVAL32,
                    DATUM
                FROM
                    DW.TEMP_PFPC_TT_VALUTRAZ
                WHERE
                    SIFRA3 = '705' AND
                    SIFVAL32 = '891'
                )
```

now I like to join this two SQL statement and would like to use ons with clause and MSsql syntax

Comment: If you're using MySQL, why have you tagged your question [tag:sql-server]? Did you mean [tag:mysql], or are you actually using Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

```
There are many ways of doing this. I only posted one way. There are some places that have been changed due to syntax issues. Let me know this answer if this answer is useful.
; WITH CTE_1 AS ( SELECT
       SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ.SIFRA3,
       SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ.SIFVAL32,
       SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ.DATUM,
       SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ.RAZMERJE
    FROM
       SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ
    WHERE
       (
          (SQLUSER.TT_VALUTRAZ.DATUM >= '1.5.2007')
       ) ---> this go to DW.TEMP_PFPC_TT_VALUTRAZ

    )

 , CTE_2 AS (


  SELECT * FROM
  (
      SELECT
        '705' AS SIFRA3,
        '891' AS SIFVAL32,
        A.DATUM,
        A.RAZMERJE AS RAZMERJE
    FROM
        DW.TEMP_PFPC_TT_VALUTRAZ A
    ) AS B
  WHERE
       B.DATUM >= '1.5.2007' AND
        B.SIFRA3 = 891 AND
        B.SIFVAL32 = 978 AND
        B.SIFRA3  NOT IN  (705) --use of sub queries in where clause has been  fixed.  
        AND B.SIFVAL32 NOT IN (891) --use of sub queries in where clause has been  fixed.  
        AND B.DATUM NOT IN  
            (
              SELECT                  
                DATUM
              FROM
                DW.TEMP_PFPC_TT_VALUTRAZ                
            )

  )

SELECT * FROM 
CTE_1 AS [C] 
  INNER JOIN   CTE_2 AS [CT]
   ON [CTE_1]. [SIFRA3] =  [CT].[SIFRA3]
     AND [C]. [SIFVAL32] =  [CT].[SIFVAL32]
     AND [C].[DATUM] = [CT].[DATUM]  
     AND [C].[RAZMERJE] =   [CT].[RAZMERJE]
```

Comment: Can you please check whether this way is wat you expected. There is another way to do this.  If you want I can add that too.  But I would be glad if you could add create table scripts which is used in the  query. That will help us to verify the correctness of the query.  Thanks :)

Comment: Code-only answers are highly discouraged. You commented that original queries had lots of issues. Where do you explain those issues and how you fixed them? Why did you not also identify and fix the use of date constants that depend on runtime factors for correct interpretation or the inconsistent use of aliases? For some strange reason you use the alias [CTE_1] for the cte named CTE_1 - that's just awkward, difficult to read, and inconsistent as well.

Comment: I added my answer and comments. Sorry if any readability issues.   @Lea Rupnik

Comment: The first SQL statement I insert in this --> DW.TEMP_PFPC_TT_VALUTRAZ then I have to do another insert with SQL 2.
THX

Comment: Does this answer provide you the solution @LeaRupnik?

Comment: No. 1. sql I insert into the table DW.TEMP_PFPC_TT_VALUTRAZ then I want to enter new values ​​in this same table and combine them all into one view.

Thanks

Comment: @LeaRupnik let me try this and give you a solution. The question is quite unclear. If you can change it a little with the requirement it would be great. but not to worry. I will help. :) Thanks